# Passing values from one partial view to another on the client side

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

is it possible send some parameter from one partialview to another .
i have 2 partial views . i wanna when i click on btn1(in partialone) , some parameters will be send to partial2 . of course without post back.
is it just possible with java script? is there any way?

for example i wanna send my td's values to second partial :

```
                          <tr>                           
                        <td class="tdPhone">2265176</td>

                         <td>Email :</td>
                        <td class="tdMobile" >fdg@gmail.com</td>

                         </tr>
                 <button class="btn btn-medium " data-type="submit">Next</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Partial views are finally rendered as divs in html page. So you will need to use client side javascript so that one div can talk to another. One of the cleanest technique will be to use triggers if you are using jquery. To send the data from one div on button click

$('body').trigger('div1-trigger-someBetterNameConventionWillHelp', [$('.tdPhone').innerHtml(),$('.tdMobile').innerHtml()]). and then another div where you wish to update it u can trap this trigger using

$('body').on('div1-trigger-someBetterNameConventionWillHelp', function(evt, data)
{

});

There is whole lot of caveat with this solution like you should try to identify the data with ids and not by classes and all, but just presenting the solution based on the question you asked.

Comment: thanks . but when we use jquery to pass parameter between two partial , is there low security , yes?

Comment: There are no security issues as you are now playing with data within the browser and you have already sent data on the client browser. So if there is any sensitive data, its already been sent to browser